# Play a wav file and change the formant (on-the-fly) in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, audio, wav

I know how to play wav files in VB.Net and string them together, etc, etc, but my question is does anyone know how to change the formant of the file (a narrative) whilst it's playing. I don't want to achieve anything too drastic, like making it sound like a chipmunk, but it would be nice to be able to change it in semitone graduations.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a command line tool like SoX (http://sox.sourceforge.net)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. It certainly  looks like a useful tool